# css position relative and stick to the top when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image in which it is set as position: relative (I can't change this due to some long explanation). Is it possible to have this img always stick to the top: 0 when the window is scrolled? I am planning to use javascript to achieve this but wondering if there's a better way. Here's the css:

```
.nav-title-logo {
  background-position: -21px -84px;
  width: 195px;
  height: 83px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: You can use `position: fixed`

Comment: I thought you said you couldn't change `position: relative`. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `position: relative;`, use `position: fixed`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need to keep it relative may have a big impact on how you choose to solve this problem.

For example, this works, but I don't know if it works for your situation. You might need to be more specific:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

img{
    position: relative;
}
```